# limit of sequence of functions define inductively using integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_0 \in L^1([0,1])$. Define $f_n(x) = (\int\limits_0^x f_{n-1}(y) dy)^{1/2}$. Assume that $f_0 \geq 0$ $a.e$ and $f_1(x) \leq f_0(x)$ $a.e$. I have proved the following:

1. $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to a function $f(x)$ that is finite everywhere on $[0,1]$.
2. $f(x) = (\int\limits_0^x f(y)dy)^{1/2}$.
3. The next question asks me to prove that if $f(x) > 0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and compute $f'(x)$. I already proved that $f'(x) = 0$. However, I failed to see why this does not hold for all $x$. Is there a counter-example?
4. Finally, I need to find an explicit formula for $f(x)$ where $f(x) \neq 0$. Using the previous part, I found that in fact $f$ is identically $0$, which seems wrong. I hope someone can provide a counter example.

Answer (score 0):

$f^{2}(x)=\int_0^{x} f(t)dt$ gives $2f(x)f'(x)=f(x)$ so $f'(x)=\frac 1  2$ when $f(x) \neq 0$. Hence, if $f(x) >0$ for all $x$, then  $f(x)=\frac x 2 +c$ where $c$ is a constant.  Also $f(0)=0$ so $c=0$.

Comment: how do i show that f'(x) exists for x > 0 though?

Comment: @CuriousAlpaca Indefinite integral of any intergrable function is continuous. By 2) it follows that $f$ is continuous. Now use the fact that integral of any continuous function is continuously differentiable. Hence $f$ is continuously differentiable.